# Acentuação da base de dados não aceite no site

Tags: html, banco-de-dados, acentuação

Tenho um texto na base de dados mas o site não assume a acentuação do tipo ã, á, ç e coloca no lugar dessas letra uns caracteres estranhos:  [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A minha base de dados está com agrupamento latin1_swedish_ci e o site lê os acentos que ponho directamente.

Como faço para o site aceitar acentuação da base de dados?

Comment: Cara, para que latin? Alguem ja falou pra vc sobre UTF-8? Tenta mudar para utf-8!

Comment: já mudei para utf-8 e não dá continua a não aceitar acentuação (meti utf-8 bin não tem apenas utf-8)

Comment: poxa, vai ver é algum problema da host, que eu saiba utf-8 e tipo universal

Comment: Agrupamento não tem nada a ver com exibição, é apenas usado para comparação e ordenação. Importante ver a codificação da tabela se está latin mesmo. Se estiver, é questão de configurar o resto da aplicação da mesma forma (headers do servidor de página, eventuais tags meta) e configurar seu editor de código para salvar na mesma codificação. Praticamente todas as (muitas) dúvidas do site sobre o assunto são relacionadas ao fato do pessoal misturar codificações na mesma aplicação.

Answer (score 0):

Existe uma séria de fatores que podem influenciar neste problema:

**1º** - Verifique a codificação do texto que está sendo salvo por seu editor de texto; 
**2º** - Verifique a codificação que está sendo utilizada em seu navegador (faça o teste em vários navegadores pra ter certeza que o problema é realmente no banco);
**3º** - Verifique a codificação do banco;
**4º** - Verifique a codificação das tabelas; 
**5º** - Verifique a codificação das células da tabela que aceitam caracteres;

Em caso extremo utilize funções, seja javascript, php ou a linguagem de sua preferência para forçar a entrada e a saída do banco na codificação correta.

Aconselho utilizar a codificação **UTF-8**, que atualmente é a mais utilizada pelos navegadores.

Comment: Essa última frase, "atualmente é a mais utilizada pelos navegadores", não faz muito sentido. Quem define o encoding é a página, não o navegador. Ele só segue o que for instruído pelo servidor ou página.

Comment: Sim, mas o default é UTF-8, por isso é, ou deveria ser, a codificação mais utilizada.

Answer (score 0):

Você está usando charsets diferentes na página e no banco, por isso o problema; de cabeça posso pensar em algumas soluções:

- Mudar o banco para UTF-8. A melhor solução de todas mas pode não ser viável
- Mudar a(s) página(s) para o mesmo charset do banco usando as tags correspondentes. Não é bem a melhor mas, dependendo da quantidade de páginas pode ser a mais fácil de implementar.
- Fazer a conversão de charset no servidor após ler do banco e antes de enviar o resultado. Me cheira a "POG" mas pode ser uma solução. Pode ser feito usando funções específicas da linguagem que está fazendo a consulta ou via banco; o mysql, por exemplo, tem as funções "cast" e "convert" que permitem converter os dados entre charsets.